# how to get js context from htmlparser2 directly?

Tags: javascript, html

how to get js context from htmlparser2 directly?

```
 var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: function(name, attribs){
        if(name === "script" && attribs.type === "text/javascript"){
            //console.log(text);
            //console.log("JS! Hooray!");
        }
    },
    ontext: function(text){
        //fs.writeFileSync("../output/test.js",text.toString());
        console.log(text);
    },
    onclosetag: function(tagname){
        if(tagname === "script"){
            //console.log("That's it?!");
        }
    }
}, {decodeEntities: true});
var input_src = fs.readFileSync('../input/test2.js', 'utf-8');
parser.write(input_src);
parser.end();
```

I try to get js from htmlparser2, but the content is not i am want.The content will include some other information expect the js. why the code do not work well?Could you give me some good ways to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything to limit the `ontext` function to only reading scripts. You need to set a flag whenever you encounter an opening script tag:

```
 var inScriptElement = false;
 var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: function(name, attribs){
        if(name === "script" && attribs.type === "text/javascript"){
            inScriptElement = true;
            //console.log(text);
            //console.log("JS! Hooray!");
        }
    },
    ontext: function(text){
        if (inScriptElement) {
            //fs.writeFileSync("../output/test.js",text.toString());
            console.log(text);
        }
    },
    onclosetag: function(tagname){
        if(tagname === "script"){
            inScriptElement = false;
            //console.log("That's it?!");
        }
    }
}, {decodeEntities: true});
```

Comment: I think the ontext should provide some more contextual information, like `ontext: function(text, tagname)`.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen That's not how event-driven parsers like this work. If you need more context you'll need to use a DOM based parser instead.

Comment: Think about I have a huge html, I'm only interested in the content of the title tag. But I want to make sure the title is right under the html/head tags and not another title tag anywhere else. When I got the title content, I will immediately stop parsing the html. What I'm doing now is I use an array/stack outside the parser to keep track of current tag path. I think it makes sense for the SAX parser to provide such context information.

Comment: SAX is based on a standardized API, so it's unlikely anything will happen their. I too once wrote a primitive wrapper class for a SAX parser in Java that did the same thing with a stack. I'm sure there are finished libraries out there that do the same, but I haven't found them yet.